# What does Lejos NXJ error 76 mean?

Tags: lejos-nxj

We're getting an error 76 for code that worked outside the lejos runtime.

What does error `76` mean?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: This may help: http://www.rz.rwth-aachen.de/global/show_document.asp?id=aaaaaaaaaacagst